# Google maps save marker location?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, location, save, latitude-longitude

So I managed to implement the google map with a dragable marker on my website. 
The only problem I have now is that I don't know how to save the location of where the marker is put the last time. So if a user drags the marker 4 times, I want to save the location (latitude and longitude) of the 4th time only.

This is what I have so far (This is the working code without the code to save the location):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

        var map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("googleMap"));
        map.addControl(new GLargeMapControl());        
        map.addControl(new GMapTypeControl());


        var centrePoint = new GLatLng('53.34870686020199', '-6.267356872558594');
        map.setCenter(centrePoint, 14); 


        var marker = new GMarker(centrePoint, {draggable: true});
        map.addOverlay(marker);


        GEvent.addListener(marker, "dragend", function() {
            var point = marker.getPoint();
            map.panTo(point);
            document.getElementById("latitude").value = point.lat();
            document.getElementById("longitude").value = point.lng();
        });

        function initialize ()
        {
        Brussels = new google.maps.LatLng (50.833333, 4.333333);

        myOptions = 
        {
        zoom: 14,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        center: Brussels,
        streetViewControl: false
        }

        map = new google.maps.Map (document.getElementById ("googleMap"), myOptions);

        marker = new google.maps.Marker ({position: Brussels, title: "Brussel, BE"});
        marker.setMap (map);
        marker.setDraggable (true);

        google.maps.event.addListener (marker, 'dragend', function (event) 
        {

        var point = marker.getPosition();
        map.panTo(point);
        });             
        }
```

Comment: It seems that you are mixing google maps api v2 and v3.

Comment: Am I? it is completely working though. I just don't know how to save the location..

Comment: You want the user not to be able to drag anymore after 4th drag?

Comment: No I want him to be able to drag as much as he wants. But I want to save the last drag only. So it gets saved in a database for example. I don't want to save all the locations the marker was put on. Only the last one.

Answer (score 4):

By save do you mean persist to local storage?

You could modify the dragend event listener so that it updates the local storage with the latitude and longitude of the position the marker was dragged to. As this event is triggered whenever the marker is dragged, the local storage will always contain the location of the last drag (i.e. if the user drags the marker 4 times, local storage will hold the position of the fourth drag).

```
google.maps.event.addListener (marker, 'dragend', function (event) 
{
    var point = marker.getPosition();
    map.panTo(point);

    // save location to local storage
    localStorage['lastLat'] = point.lat();
    localStorage['lastLng'] = point.lng();
});
```

Obviously this would only work in browsers that have support for local storage so it would be wise to check for this before attempting to access the local storage

Comment: I want it to look like this:
http://universimmedia.pagesperso-orange.fr/geo/loc.htm

Exactly the same, I want to get my longitude and latitude to change when I move the marker. And then be able to save it to a database for example. I'm pretty new at this :/ Hope I explained well

Comment: That's exactly what I mean! Thank you very much man. Now do you know how I can save the location to a database for example? using php?

Comment: Is this a webapp running on a server? You could fire off an Ajax call to the server in the 'dragend' event listener passing a username, latitude and longitude as parameters. The server would then update the last location for the specified user based with the new latitude and longitude.