# Send and display a map location query to a saved google map

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, kml, mymaps

I have a basic map query that I am sending to google maps from another cloud based platform (netsuite) that looks like this:

http://maps.google.com/maps?q={custentity_street}

where {custentity_street} is equal to a street address.

This does a great job of placing a marker at the street address on a plain google map.

However I would like to place this marker on a previously saved google map from my maps collection, but I am not sure where to start with this. Simply grabbing the URL from the browser or the Embed code and adding the maps?q=... command to it does not seem to work.

Any ideas would be much appreciated.

Comment: what have you done so far? please provide minimal, complete and verifiable example. Here's a related SO ticket: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21931638/google-maps-save-marker-location